# Primefaces autocomplete not working and showing no exception

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am new to primefaces and I want to use autocomplete tag of primeface.So i folllowed [this example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteBasic.jsf).
Here is my code

## layout.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>

<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="form">  
    <p:panel header="AutoComplete" toggleable="true" id="panel">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  

            <h:outputLabel value="Simple :" for="acSimple" />  
            <p:autoComplete id="acSimple" value="#{autoCompleteBean.txt1}"   
                    completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.complete}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

## AutoCompleteBean.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
@ManagedBean(name="autoCompleteBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AutoCompleteBean {  

    private String txt1;  

    public List<String> complete(String query) {  
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();  

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
            results.add(query + i);  
        }  

        return results;  
    }  

    public String getTxt1() {  
        return txt1;  
    }  

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {  
        this.txt1 = txt1;  
    }  
}
```

so layout.xhtml renders fine and show me a text field but after then it don't work and not showing autocomplete functionality.
Is there something missing? or what would be the problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xhtml you have posted is using standard html tags for ***head*** and ***body*** so it may not be correctly interpreting the Javascript used to call the complete method in the bean.

Try using ***h:head*** and ***h:body***.

The tip-off may show up in your output window.  Check for something like:

```
sourceId=null[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.), detail=(One or more resources have the target of 'head', but no 'head' component has been defined within the view.)]
```

See the Stack Overflow discussion on h:head in primefaces: [What's the difference between <h:head> and <head> in Java Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028105/whats-the-difference-between-hhead-and-head-in-java-facelets)

Answer (score 0):

You should always use **h:head** and **h:body** when you are writing facelets. The reason is that in order for the auto complete to work javascript is required and if you don't include h:head jsf will not be able to put the javascript correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, however in my case the problem was resolved when I removed a **p** tag which was surrounding the **p:autocomplete** tag.

The following code will not throw an error message, but the autoselect dropdown menu won't appear. After removing the `<p></p>` everything works fine.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p>
            <p:autoComplete id="place" value="#{addPlaceBean.place}"
                completeMethod="#{autoCompletePlace.completePlace}" var="place"
            itemLabel="#{place.city}, #{place.country}"
            itemValue="#{place}" converter="placeConverter">
            </p:autoComplete>
        </p>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you really, really sure? I cannot imagine this. Wasn't there any css on the p tag that caused problems?

Comment: I tried it now with a minimal example (see above) and the problem is still the same.