# PrimeFaces components are not displayed

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, primefaces, xhtml

I'm developing an application using JSF with PrimeFaces. I've a problem in the Facelets page where < p:xxx > tags are not displayed in the page. Every      < p: xxx >      tags are diplayed like a simple inputText.

This is the start of my xhtml page

```
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

and this part of the web.xml page

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've got also the primefaces-4.0.jar in the folder WEBContent/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-4.0.jar

Comment: Thanks @Makky I have already created pages with primefaces components in eclipse and are displayed correctly but now in this specific page are not diplayed. I don't think it is a problem of configuration of eclipse

Comment: The Primesfaces' tags are not underlined by yellow color by the IDE ?

Comment: no, there is no yellow or red underscore

Comment: Where is the rest of your page? Do you have `<h:head/>` defined on the page?

Comment: thanks @kolossus ! this works fine. I 've forgotten the "h" in the head's tag. Can you put your answer as the predefined one so I can check it as the correct one?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `<h:head/>` tag in your page. This tag defines the region in which the JSF runtime can inject the necessary javascripts for rendering elements and processing ajax in your page.

Related:

- [What's the difference between <h:head> and <head> in Java Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028105/1530938)

Comment: Is there a typo here? Shouldn't it be </h:head> ?

Comment: `</h:head>` would be just the closing tag @nAQ. `<h:head/>` is the complete tag, the same as typing `<h:head></h:head>`.