# PrimeFaces <p:tabView> shows all tabs in the same time

Tags: eclipse, jsf, primefaces, tabview

I created a Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse Neon 3 to try some PrimeFaces showcase example out. I have put the `primefaces-6.1.jar` into the classpath of the [war project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nO04M.png). The JSF implementation is Mojarra 2.2. 
The `<p:tabView>` appears in a very distinct way as in the showcase. 
The tab titles appears just single links (nothing tab like appearance) and all the tabs are visible in the same time below.

I copy/paste the basic tabview part of the example into an empty facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<title>JSF Facelet</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h:form id="form">

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

    <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Basic</h3>
    <p:tabView>
      <p:tab title="Godfather Part I">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
          <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />
          <h:outputText value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab title="Godfather Part II">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
          <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />
          <h:outputText value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
      </p:tab>
      <p:tab title="Godfather Part III">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
          <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />
          <h:outputText value="After a break of more than 15 years..." />
        </h:panelGrid>
      </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
  </h:form>
</body>    
</html>
```

The generated page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
  <title>JSF Facelet</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/EEApp1-war/faces/index.xhtml;jsessionid=02c69d11b0bfea5adbc5c27cfa33" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" />


    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"></p:growl>

    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Basic</h3>
    <p:tabView>
        <p:tab title="Godfather Part I"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg"></p:graphicImage></td>
<td>The story begins as Don Vito Corleone...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Godfather Part II"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg"></p:graphicImage></td>
<td>Francis Ford Coppola's legendary...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="Godfather Part III"><table cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
                <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg"></p:graphicImage></td>
<td>After a break of more than 15 years...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-152009560656088582:-2166935493356532768" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

[The view of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmkit.png)

My question is : what have I missed to set to get the same appearance just as like in the showcase?
As I can see the generated code contains `<p:growl>`, `<p:tabView>`, `<p:tab>` and `<p:graphicImage>` elements. The editor does not show any error (it finds them by the namespace). The `<h:*>` elements got rendered. Why does not it render the `<p:*>` elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between <h:head> and <head> in Java Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028105/whats-the-difference-between-hhead-and-head-in-java-facelets)

Comment: Sorry, I was maybe to quick in my duplicate. Did you check if the primefaces jar was actually deployed when running the application?